# Embedding Youtube video shows blank screen

Tags: ios, webview, youtube

Starting with the facts:

1. I am using the popular code snippet that creates an  object and loads it into a webview.
2. I am using a device.
3. I've tested that the webview gets loaded by adding a  tag into it, it's all fine.

The issue is that the embedded object shows up blank and obviously unclickable and I've been googling for hours and I can't seem to see why that's happening. I've even created an html document and tested it with my computer's browser, the thumbnail shows fine but I can't get it to show in my webview, any help please?

UPDATING for further info, by pasting the video's URL, I got it to work somehow BUT the code that I am using does not seem to produce a 'clean' video URL, instead it produces something like this: https://www.youtube.com/v/pzhL7jpsiNw?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata

With my trial and error attempt I realized I need something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzhL7jpsiNw

The code that produces the first one, taken from various GDATA tutorials I've been browsing is this.

```
GDataEntryBase *entry2 = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *contents = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry2 mediaGroup] mediaContents];
[self embedYouTube:[NSURL URLWithString:[[contents objectAtIndex:0] URLString]] frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
```

with `[NSURL URLWithString:[[contents objectAtIndex:0] URLString]]` producing the 'verbose' version of the link.

Apart from starting to manipulate the string itself which I consider rather dirty, is there a way (I am kinda clueless regarding GDATA API and there's no time to dive into it atm) to get the desired URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you didn't want to do string manipulation, but I personally don't think that stripping off GET parameters by splitting the string at the `?` is particularly dirty.

For instance:

```
NSString *dirty = @"https://www.youtube.com/v/pzhL7jpsiNw?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata";
NSString *clean = [[dirty componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@",clean);
```

Gives you https://www.youtube.com/v/pzhL7jpsiNw.

If you need you can then grab the video ID by splitting at `/v/`.

```
NSString *vid = [[clean componentsSeparatedByString:@"/v/"] objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *newURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@",vid];
```

Comment: got too tired of trying to find the 'right way' ended up doing this instead, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys just discovering Little fix for this. I have added embedded video to

```
?html5=1
```

then Video will render the HTML5 Player instead of Flash player.

Thanks.